# Change Windows 8 start menu back to Windows 7

Tags: windows-8-preview, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I turn off Modern UI and get the old Start Menu back in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/462687/how-do-i-turn-off-modern-ui-and-get-the-old-start-menu-back-in-windows-8)

I just installed Windows 8 Consumer Preview edition and I tried to modify the `RPEnabled` to 0, so I can have the Windows 7 Start Menu.

After a restart, the Metro UI menu is still there. Does anyone what is causing this? This should work.

Comment: In the Developer Preview, the Metro UI was just an addition as they were actively developing the first bits of the Metro UI at that time. With the Consumer Preview, they replaced the actual Start Menu code and don't support that registry key anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here’s how to do it,
>
> - First of all download the [Vistart app](http://www.lee-soft.com/vistart/) make sure that you skip the additional optional downloads while installing the app).
> - After installing the app you will get the Start button on the taskbar,but it will overlap with the first pinned taskbar icon.
> - The Start button overlaps the Internet Explorer icon to fix that issue,you have to create a new toolbar using the following steps,
>
>   - Create a New Folder on Desktop
>   - After Creating the folder  you need to Right Click on the Windows Taskbar >Toolbars >New Toolbar to create new toolbar from the menu
>   - Browse through the  newly created folder and select the folder.
>   - Now right-click on the  taskbar and uncheck “Lock The Taskbar”option from the menu.
>   - This will unlock the Taskbar so now you can move the “New Folder” Taskbar element anywhere on the Taskbar,so position the element to the
>       Start Orb.
>   - Now right click on the taskbar element “New folder”  which is under the Start orb and uncheck the  “Show Text” and “Show title” in the
>       menu.
>
> Now you have the Start Button and the Start Menu running on your
>   Windows 8 Consumer Preview  :)

[Source and Screenshots are located here](http://windows8beta.com/2012/03/enable-start-orb-and-start-menu-on-windows-8-consumer-preview)

Comment: Please don't 1:1 copy and paste other content. At least quote it, too, to show which parts you have written. It'd be great to summarize in your own words, so as not to plagiarize from other sites.

Comment: I can't ask the same question to different forums?

Comment: This is just a software acting like the "old" start menu. Not sure this is what l people want if they read the question. I want the start menue back... i don't want a software acting similar to the start menu... Maybe you can make this clear. The installation of the app doesn't remove some settings or stuff, it is just a nice shaped windows program looking like the old start menu

Comment: As Tom Wijsman stated above, there isn't a way to hack the start menu orb back, the only way to do it now is to install an application.

Answer (score 1):

This is my favorite:

http://startisback.com/

it adds the original Windows 7 startmenu back (which is still present in Win8 but disabled).

> **How is it possible for Windows 8 to have real start menu? Microsoft said they did remove it!**
>
> They did, but not completely. Removing start menu completely would require rearchitecting some key Windows code base and raising compatibility issues which they couldn't seemingly afford. StartIsBack reuses large portion of start menu code left, but contains a large amount of code to make as well it work as you expect and new functions too.

Answer (score 0):

There are many applications to get a start menu in Windows 8. Based on [What W8 start button solution do you prefer?](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/poll.php?pollid=187&do=showresults), these are the highest polled options (at time of posting 29/10/2012):

- [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/) (free!) **40%**
- [Start8](http://www.stardock.com/products/start8/index.asp) ($5) **27%**
- [Power 8 (by Power8 Team)](http://code.google.com/p/power8/) (free) **3.4%**
- [ViStart (by Lee Matthew Chantrey)](http://lee-soft.com/vistart/) (free) **2.3%**
- [StartMenu8 (by IObit)](http://www.startmenu8.com/index.html) (free) **2.3%**
- [Start Menu X (by OrdinarySoft)](http://www.startmenux.com/index.html) (free) **1.1%**
- [Spesoft Free Windows 8 Start Menu (by Spesoft)](http://www.spesoft.com/free-windows-8-start-menu.aspx) (free) **0%**
- [Revel BringBack 2012 (by RevelSoftware)](http://www.revel-software.it/BringBack.aspx) (free) **0%**
- [Handy Start Menu (by HandyStartMenu)](http://www.handystartmenu.com/) (free) **0%**

Other options not polled are:

- [Pokki](https://www.pokki.com/) (free!)
- [StartMenu7](http://www.startmenu7.com/index.html) (free with pro version for sale)
- [Wentutu](http://www.wentutu.com/windows8startmenu.html)
- [Start Button 8](http://www.startbutton8.com/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of trying to get the Start Menu back, get used to the Start Screen. If you use the Start Menu like many users, not much will change. For instance:

- If you click in the bottom left corner or press the Windows key to bring up Start
- If you use the Search function of the Start Menu/Screen to search for apps/options
- If you use the Start Menu to get to My Computer/Control Panel/etc, what you do now is right click the bottom left corner. Windows Explorer takes you to My Computer.

The main difference will be where your favorite apps are placed. Instead of having the commonly used programs on the left side of the Start Menu, you get the Start Screen with tiles, and you have to organize them by yourself.